# How to access array indices in REBOL multidimensional arrays

Tags: rebol

I tried using an array to specify an index of a 2-dimensional array, but the `pick` function won't accept an array as the second element:

```
print pick [[3 5] [3 1]] [2 1]

*** ERROR
** Script error: invalid argument: [2 2]
** Where: pick try do either either either -apply-
** Near: pick [[3 5] [3 1]] [2 2]
```

I found a workaround for this, but it's slightly more verbose:

```
print pick pick [[3 5] [3 1]] 2 1
[comment This prints "3".]
```

Is it possible to access an index of a multidimensional array without calling the `pick` function multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more succinct way to [`PICK`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/pick.html) out an element from a multi-dimensonal array is to use the [`PATH!`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/datatypes/path.html) syntax.

Here's an example in the Rebol console:

```
>> x: [[3 5] [3 1]]     
== [[3 5] [3 1]]

>> x/2/1
== 3

>> x/2/2                      
== 1

>> x/1/(1 + 1)      ;; use parens for expressions - transforms to x/1/2
== 5

>> p: 2
== 2

>> x/1/:p           ;; use ":" for variable reference - transforms to x/1/2 
== 5

>> x/(p - 1)/:p     ;; mix and match at any level of array - transforms to x/1/2
== 5    

>> x/3              ;; NONE is returned if index does not exist
== none

>> x/2
== [3 1]

>> x/2/3            ;; again out of range
== none
```

Another alternative would be the [`FIRST`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/first.html), [`SECOND`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/second.html) .. [`TENTH`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/tenth.html) functions:

```
>> second first [[3 5] [3 1]] 
== 5
```

You can even mix and match:

```
>> x: [ [[1]] [[2]] [3 [4 5]] ]
== [[[1]] [[2]] [3 [4 5]]]

>> first pick x/3 2
== 4
```

Comment: Would there be any way to include expressions in the PATH! syntax, such as `x/(10 + 1)/3`? or `x/(3 + 4)/10`? I've tried both of these, and they always return `none`.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - Yes you can.  I'll update the answer with some examples.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - PS.  for your comment examples to work remember spaces - `x/(var1 + 1)` and `x/(3 + 4)`.  Update - You've amended your comment since my comment!  Your new examples are returning `none` because those indices are out of range.  I'll add this to my examples.

Comment: I've run into another problem: `print (split "hello,world,wow" ",")/3` doesn't print the 3rd element in the output of the `split` function.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I consider this to be a bug.  Some discussion of this design issue can be found [in CureCode ticket 2094](http://curecode.org/rebol3/ticket.rsp?id=2094&cursor=1).  *(See [here](https://trello.com/c/N9ZKFfGI) notes on what CureCode is and why we haven't gotten moved to GitHub yet.)*  It's a good time to work it out as Rebol3 and Red are being standardized.  Please feel free to come talk in the [Rebol and Red chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red) and lend your voice to that (and other) pressing issues!

Comment: @AndersonGreen - Unfortunately that doesn't work.  If you want to know the detail then it's best to post it as a new question.  In meantime you can do: `print pick split "hello,world,wow" "," 3`